# Set/Change number of visible recent posts on magento blog

Tags: php, magento-1.9, blogs

I am using MDL Blog in magento 1.9.2.0 ... my blog page is showing only last recent 10 posts and same thing happening in right side bar..  I want to show all post on a page and sidebar also . 
My code is :

```
    <?php if ($posts = $this->getRecent()): ?>
    <div class="menu-recent magicat-container">
            <ul class="listStyle">
                <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
                    <li><span><a href="<?php echo $post->getAddress(); ?>" ><?php echo $post->getTitle(); ?></a></span></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please share getRecent() function code also, then i will give you solutions.

Comment: recent code in sidebar.php file

<?php

class Magic_Mdlblog_Block_Menu_Sidebar extends Magic_Mdlblog_Block_Abstract
{
    public function getRecent()
    {
        // widget declaration
        if ($this->getBlogWidgetRecentCount()) {
            $size = $this->getBlogWidgetRecentCount();
        } else {
            // standard output
            $size = self::$_helper->getRecentPage();
        }

Comment: Hmm it not defined limit in this function so can you please share code also this function?
getBlogWidgetRecentCount()
$_helper->getRecentPage()